# access to several navigation items in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I've developed android app for a while, however I just started swift.
I'm going to develop an app which its android version have about 10~12 items in side bar drawer menu.

I want to know are there any best practice for iOS to have about 10 items on side bar drawers, using third party libraries or  there are some other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can find many types of Side menu from cocoacontrols. According to your requirement, download any.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=side+menu

Answer (score 2):

If you need some 3rd party library for side menus, you can easily use some of these

- [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)
- [SideMenuController](https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController)
- [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)

to simply install them you can use [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) (on this website you can also find other 3rd party libraries)

---

Anyway, my preferences are not to use these side/slide/hamburger menus and instead you should reorganize your app and you should rather think about [`UITabBarController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: I think TabBar would be ok, however I don't know what to do when number of items are more than 5 or 7 items? Should I rethink my application and bring items to a dashboard like page or there are some other suggestions?

Comment: @VSB it really depends on your specific needs. But I would rethink it and have max 5 tab items.

Answer (score 1):

simple and easy to implement swift slideMenu (with custom UI)

[AKSlideMenu](https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help
https://github.com/SURYAKANTSHARMA/SKSideMenu.
You can drag it into your project or customize this